# accessing ListViewItem via pwinauto

Tags: python, listviewitem, pywinauto

pywinauto recognized my GUI object as listview. The gui object is a grid with checkboxes in each cell. I am trying to click a certain checkbox via a ListView.items()[index], item operation. (all the items, checkboxes, are recognized and reside under ListView.items()).

The problem is that some of the items aren't responding to clicks.
For example: the following code only clicks successfully on 60% of the items.

I have tried to click in any other possible way, using click,select,check and using the double=True flag via click.

```
for item in self.curr_win.ListView5.items():
    item.click()
```

*self.curr_win.ListView5 is my list view object

- I need a way to control all the checkboxes, I would appreciate any help!
- A picture of the GUI object is below

[image]

Comment: try adding a delay after click i.e. time.sleep(0.25)

Comment: Which backend are you using? I mean is it just `Application()` or `Application(backend="uia")`? Two backends have different wrappers for ListView.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I'm using the default, since uia backend responds after really long time. I'm not sure why, I saw an open bug on this one. While saying really slow, I mean 5-6  seconds for a click, sometimes more. https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/256

Comment: @SachinPatole, it doesn't matter. the ListView Object contains all the items (which are displayed in the gui) although, when I click on some of them, nothing happens. 
* I tried clicking on the items via Evaluate Expression (Pycharm) 
The code is just there to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I updated the problem to be more informative, I can provide a screenshot if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

OK, for "win32" backend you can use these docs for `ListViewWrapper` and `_listview_item` objects: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.common_controls.html#pywinauto.controls.common_controls._listview_item

```
for item in self.curr_win.ListView5.items():
    item.click(where="check")
    # or
    # item.click_input(where="check")
```

Item method `.ensure_visible()` makes automatic scrolling for invisible items.

The difference in method `.click_input()` is that it moves real mouse cursor that can make all the actions more visible while debugging.

Comment: Hi Vasily,
Firstly, Thanks for your help!
I just tried to use the item.click(where="check") option, although the command prompted an error - RuntimeError: Area ('check') not found for this list view item
* I just added a screen of the ListView object grid to the question, I hope it helps
I verified I'm clicking the right object, it has 36 items in total, exactly like the picture, 36 checkboxes. Although the clicks still doesn't work properly.

Comment: I used swapy/py_inspect inspection tools to make sure it is the right ListView object.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe these checkboxes are self-drawn. But you may have another chance to use `Application(backend="uia")` (choose "uia" backend in py_inspect as well). You can identify each single item using "uia" and explore its methods as for any other wrapper object.

Comment: in uia mode, the GUI object is identified as ListBox5 with control_type=List,
I tried to access a single cell with ListBox5.cells(). I got 6 items. each Item has a list of 6  StaticWrapper objects (each StaticWrapper is representing a cell). although I cannot activate the function click/check upon a certain cell object.
I tried using ListBox5.items(), while getting a 6 ListItemWrapper objects. Although, it looks like these objects doesn't support click/check functions. Regardless, the UIA mode is responding slow, sometimes 20-30 seconds per operation. any Ideas?

Comment: This thread may help: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/256